# Is the base class constructor excuted if the derived class does not have a constructor?

Tags: c++

This a basic concept that I'm not sure of, and I need to have a clearer understanding.
My question is, does the base class constructor get executed even if the derived class does not have a constructor? Or is the base constructor call not related to the derived constructor?
Thank you for explaining!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes Sure , The base class constructor get executed even if your derived class has no constructor

Answer (score 0):

A constructor is always executed for every base class. This includes compiler-generated default constructors. If it's not possible to call a base class constructor, you will always get an error message.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, by default, the default constructor of the base class is executed.

Note that this applies for all derived class constructors - they all call the default constructor unless you specify a different one. This means that a copy constructor in a derived class (user-defined or compiler generated) will, by default, call the default base class constructor.

Comment: ok so if the base class default constructor let's say has a cout that prints something meaning it was defined be me , then this will get excuted ? or you mean by "the default constructor" is the comppiler generated ?

Comment: @user2971537 a default constructor is one that can be called without any parameters (it can be user defined or generated). And yes, it should print.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, the base class's constructor will get called before the derived class's constructor.

Here's a good SO thread explaining it: [Does a base class's constructor and destructor get called with the derived ones?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1640414/does-a-base-classs-constructor-and-destructor-get-called-with-the-derived-ones)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If not defined the compiler conjures up one for you and uses that

Answer (score 0):

Even if you do not define a constructor by yourselves, default constructor will be added by the compiler.

By default, derived class constructor will call the default constructor of the base class before the execution of the body of the derived class constructor.

If you want, you can call the constructor of the base class in the initialization list of the constructor of the derived class.

Here is an example.

```
class Base
{
public:
    Base(int nValue)
    {
        //body of the constructor
    }
};

class Derived: public Base
{
public:

    Derived(int mnValue) :Base(mnValue)
    {
        //body of the constructor
    }
};
```

In the above example, derived class call the constructor of the Base class explicitly in the initialization list of the constructor of the derived class.

For more information, please refer to

http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/113-order-of-construction-of-derived-classes/

http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/114-constructors-and-initialization-of-derived-classes/

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you create an object its constructor runs. Whenever you destroy an object its destructor runs. Regardless of whether the object is a member, a base, or anything else. That's fundamental to object-oriented programming.